# can't implement L.mapbox.simplestyle with geoJson

Tags: leaflet, geojson, mapbox, geo

I'm trying to implement simplestyle's options for marker size and color , but can't get them to render. In this simple test case, I'm trying to follow [Mapbox's own example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geojson-simplestyle/) quite closely:

```
var myData = [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [4.509373,51.932994]
        },
        "properties": {
             "marker-size": "large",
             "marker-color": "#ffcc00"
        }
      }
    ];

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-20v6611k')
    .setView([51.932994,4.509373], 8);

L.geoJson(myData, { style: L.mapbox.simplestyle.style }).addTo(map);
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/webstax/W763Z/1/)

But the marker renders in default style. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've got it working using this extended function from [this page](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geojson-marker-style/) of Mapbox's documentation:

```
L.geoJson(myData, {
    pointToLayer: L.mapbox.marker.style,
    style: function(feature) { return feature.properties; }
}).addTo(map);
```

The other Mapbox example didn't make it look like the pointToLayer argument was required, but whatever works:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webstax/W763Z/3/)

Comment: Yep, Leaflet has different code paths for points and non-points.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you don't have access to 'myData' object? Other words, how to do it client-side ? It's not working for me: see my SO here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609348/leaflet-and-mapbox-styling-mapbox-markers-using-l-geojson

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to create a featureLayer based on your myData:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(myData).addTo(map);
```

Your data will have to be an object, however, and not an array:

```
var myData = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [4.509373,51.932994]
    },
    "properties": {
         "marker-size": "large",
         "marker-color": "#ffcc00"
    }
  };
```