# Leaflet and Mapbox: Styling mapbox markers using L.geoJson?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to style my marker color using Mapbox's simple-style syntax within a L.geoJson function like so:

```
L.geoJson(myData, {
    pointToLayer: L.mapbox.marker.style,
    style: function(feature){ 
        return { 'marker-color': '#ffcc00' } 
    }
});
```

According to [mapbox docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.3/l-mapbox-marker-style/), you can use L.mapbox.marker.style within L.geoJson for mapbox's default markers, but I can't seem to figure out how to style it with a different color.

There was a [similar question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962684/cant-implement-l-mapbox-simplestyle-with-geojson) but I could not get it work in my client-side code.

Does anyone know how to do this? Here's a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webstax/W763Z/3/) to get started.

*Note: I know marker attributes can be added to the actual data that is being consumed, but I need to be able to style the marker within the client-side code because I won't have access to the geoJson featureCollection*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot rely on your GeoJSON data having styling properties already defined, you simply need to "patch" it with your own style before passing each feature to `L.mapbox.marker.style`.

```js
L.geoJson(myData, {
    // Instead of passing directly L.mapbox.marker.style function,
    // implement your own that will first "patch" the current feature
    // with your desired styling properties.
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        feature.properties = {
            "marker-size": "large",
            "marker-color": "#cc0000"
        };
        // Finally call L.mapbox.marker.style with the "patched" feature.
        return L.mapbox.marker.style(feature, latlng);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W763Z/6/

Comment: Thanks, step in the right direction. Unfortunately, something happens when you add the onEachFunction option to the feature. See your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W763Z/7/

Comment: 2 issues: you removed a comma from the GeoJSON data, which became invalid; if you want to still be able to access some feature properties defined in the GeoJSON, you should **extend** the `feature.properties` object rather than overwriting it. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W763Z/8/